# External drive doesn't mount

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mount, kde, dolphin

I was transferring a file from my external hard drive to a USB device on my laptop, which runs Arch Linux with the KDE desktop environment. After the transfer reached 30%, I paused it and put my laptop to sleep. When I woke up my laptop, I can't mount my external hard drive, and it gave me this error message in Dolphin:

> An error occurred while accessing 'drive 1', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error mounting /dev/sdb5 at /run/media/[USERNAME]/drive 1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb5, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

My external drive is formatted as NTFS, while my internal SSD is formatted as F2FS.

---

---

I used ChatGPT 3.5 and gave me this solution, but it's not working!

It seems like there might have been an issue with the external hard drive's filesystem when it was disconnected or unmounted improperly. This can sometimes happen if a filesystem is not properly synced or if there are errors during the transfer process.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. **Check the filesystem on the external hard drive:** First, you'll need to check and repair the filesystem on the external hard drive. Since it's NTFS, you can use the **`ntfsfix`** utility to attempt to fix any issues:

   ```
   sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb5
   ```

   Replace **`/dev/sdb5`** with the appropriate device for your external hard drive.
2. **Mount the external hard drive manually:** After running **`ntfsfix`**, try to manually mount the external hard drive using the following command:

   ```
   sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb5 /mnt
   ```

   If the mount is successful, you should be able to access the files on the external hard drive under the **`/mnt`** directory.
3. **Check the filesystem for errors:** Once the external hard drive is mounted, you can check the filesystem for errors using the following command:

   ```
   sudo ntfsck /dev/sdb5
   ```

   This command will check the filesystem for errors and attempt to fix them.
4. **Unplug and reconnect the external hard drive:** Sometimes, simply unplugging and reconnecting the external hard drive can resolve mounting issues. After reconnecting the drive, try accessing it again through Dolphin or your file manager.

---

I want to be able to mount my External Hard Drive again! and FIX the issue.